# Why is ReadOnlyDoubleProperty not a Double?

Tags: java, double, javafx

I found some javaFX piece of code on the internet which doesn't even compile.

```
tableView.widthProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener< Double >(){
    @Override
    public void changed(final ObservableValue<? extends Double> observableValue, final Double aDouble, final Double aDouble2) {
        //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }
});
```

The error shown by IntelliJ is:

Cannot resolve method 'addListener(javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener<'java.lang.Double>)'

On the other hand, this compiles and works great.

```
    tableView.widthProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(final ObservableValue<? extends Number> observableValue, final Number number, final Number number2) {
            //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }
    });
```

As you can see the only difference here is that the new ChangeListener uses a Number and not a Double (which extends Number).

The WidthProperty is a ReadOnlyDoubleProperty which extends DoubleExpression and implements ReadOnlyProperty<'java.lang.Number>.

This may be basic Java, but I really don't see why it doesn't compile, but does for others.

Comment: `ReadOnlyDoubleProperty` implements `ObservableValue<Number>` which expects a `ChangeListener<? super Number>`, and `Double` is not a super class of `Number`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the documents, [`ReadOnlyDoubleProperty`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/beans/property/ReadOnlyDoubleProperty.html) implements [`ObservableValue<Number>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/beans/value/ObservableValue.html), which have a method `void addListener(ChangeListener<? super Number> listener)`

So you need to pass in a `ChangeListener<T>` where `T` is a super type of `Number` or `Number` itself. `Double` is not a super type of `Number`, so you cannot pass in a `ChangeListener<Double>`.

Comment: Thanks for the clear as cristal answer. I'll try to find where I found that impossible piece of code. Good evening!